# NullReferenceException on type initializer

Tags: f#, mono, monodevelop

I was playing with F# types and datastructures in the following code (I'm using Monodevelop on a Mac and this only happens in the Interactive):

```
type UnbalancedSet<'a> =
    | E
    | T of UnbalancedSet<'a> * 'a * UnbalancedSet<'a>

let rec insert x = function
    | E -> T(E, x, E)
    | T(a, y, b) as s -> 
        if x < y then T(insert x a, y, b)
        elif x > y then T(a, y, insert x b)
        else s
```

It works great with simple types as ints floats and chars but when it comes to strings or tuples it gives the following error:

```
let a = insert (3, 9) E;;

System.TypeInitializationException: An exception was thrown by the type initializer for UnbalancedSet`1 ---> System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
  at FSI_0004+UnbalancedSet`1[System.Tuple`2[System.Int32,System.Int32]]..cctor () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
  at <StartupCode$FSI_0004>.$FSI_0004.main@ () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at (wrapper managed-to-native) System.Reflection.MonoMethod:InternalInvoke (System.Reflection.MonoMethod,object,object[],System.Exception&)
  at System.Reflection.MonoMethod.Invoke (System.Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, System.Reflection.Binder binder, System.Object[] parameters, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
Stopped due to error
```

I don't understand what's going on. I expected this code to work since the type is comparable. Any clues?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This looks like a MonoDevelop issue -- I'm able to run your example code just fine in F# Interactive in VS2010:

```
> let a = insert (3, 9) E;;

val a : UnbalancedSet<int * int> = T (E,(3, 9),E)
```

Unless anyone else has run into this same issue and posts the solution here, you should try posting this to the MonoDevelop mailing list and/or asking the #monodevelop channel on GIMPnet IRC.

http://monodevelop.com/index.php?title=Help_%26_Contact

Comment: The "cctor" in the error message means that the error is in the static constructor of the UnbalancedSet type. BTW it works fine with VS2012.

Comment: I found this only happens in the Interactive. When I compile the code and run it, works fine. I updated the question with that information. I'll post it in the #monodevelop channel because it seems to be a Monodevelop issue.

Comment: It could be a Mono issue rather than a MonoDevelop issue per se.  FSI relies on the Reflection.Emit libraries but compiled code doesn't, so it's certainly possible that there's something that Mono's implementation of those libraries does differently than the standard .NET CLR.

Comment: Right using Interactive in the terminal also fails.

Comment: @curial - what are your mono and fsi versions?

Comment: @JohnPalmer for mono 3.0.3 and for fsi it uses F# 3.0